# Fubini's Theorem with Single-Variable Functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

### 1 Fubini's Theorem with $f(x,y)$

According to Wikipedia:

> [image]

Notice in particular that $f$ takes multi-variable form $f(x,y)$ within the integral.

### 2 Fubini's Theorem with $f(y)$

Now consider from a passage in my textbook:

> [image]

Here the name "Fubini's Theorem" is invoked but with functions under the integrand that fail to take the form $f(x,y)$.

**Question:** How to reconcile this?

Comment: Define $h(y,\theta)=f(y)g(\theta -y)e^{-in\theta} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By observing that: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(y,\theta)dyd\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(y,\theta)d\theta dy$$where: $$h(y,\theta)=f(y)g(\theta-y)e^{-in\theta}$$

---

edit to make things more clear.

$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left[\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)g(\theta-y)dy\right]e^{-in\theta}d\theta & =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)g(\theta-y)e^{-in\theta}dyd\theta\\
 & =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)g(\theta-y)e^{-in\theta}d\theta dy\\
 & =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(y\right)\left[\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(\theta-y)e^{-in\theta}d\theta\right]dy
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: But nowhere does $f(y)g(\theta -y) e^{-n\theta}$ show up in the equation without being split up by an integral.

Comment: That is no issue. It is well known that e.g. $\int f(x)\int g(y)dydx=\int\int f(x)g(y)dydx$

Comment: So, it seems "user" would need an extra step in the middle, where everything is inside both integrals.  You can do that.  And then, after a few times, you won't need to do that.

Comment: @drhab Is there is a name for that lemma? Or a resource to study its proof?

Comment: It is elementary. Are you familiar with $\int cg(y)dy=c\int g(y)dy$ where $c$ is a constant? For that reason we also have for every $x$ that $\int f(x)g(y)dy=f(x)\int g(y)dy$ and consequently  $\int\int f(x)g(y)dydx=\int f(x)\int g(y)dydx$

Comment: @drhab Very complete answer. I totally understand everything now, thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome.